# How to grab city names in Google reverse geocoding with Python

Tags: python, google-geocoding-api

I have a major problem with Google reverse geocoding. I received the geo info with my API key, but I cannot use one syntax to grab the city names because the city names are in different position. I have a list of almost 2000 coordinates in Japan. Please help. Thank you so much! Let me explain in detail

These coordinates (35.098129999999998, 135.71893) return me the below info, to grab the city, I need to slice [2]['short_name'], notice 'types' is 'locality'.

```
[{'long_name': 'Unnamed Road', 'short_name': 'Unnamed Road', 'types':                   ['route']}, 
{'long_name': 'Kita-ku', 'short_name': 'Kita-ku', 'types': ['political', 'sublocality', 'sublocality_level_1']}, 
{'long_name': 'Kyōto-shi', 'short_name': 'Kyōto-shi', 'types': ['locality', 'political']}, 
{'long_name': 'Kyōto-fu', 'short_name': 'Kyōto-fu', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']}, 
{'long_name': 'Japan', 'short_name': 'JP', 'types': ['country', 'political']}]
```

These coordinates (26.211069999999999, 127.6876) return me the below info, to grab the city name I need to slice [4]['short_name'], notice 'types' is also 'locality'.

```
[{'long_name': '29', 'short_name': '29', 'types': ['premise']},     
{'long_name': '4', 'short_name': '4', 'types': ['political', 'sublocality', 'sublocality_level_4']}, 
{'long_name': '1 Chome', 'short_name': '1 Chome', 'types': ['political', 'sublocality', 'sublocality_level_3']}, 
{'long_name': 'Higawa', 'short_name': 'Higawa', 'types': ['political', 'sublocality', 'sublocality_level_2']}, 
{'long_name': 'Naha-shi', 'short_name': 'Naha-shi', 'types': ['locality', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'Okinawa-ken', 'short_name': 'Okinawa-ken', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']},  
{'long_name': 'Japan', 'short_name': 'JP', 'types': ['country', 'political']}, {'long_name': '900-0022', 'short_name': '900-0022', 'types': ['postal_code']}]
```

These coordinates (35.670479999999998, 139.74091999999999) return me the below info, to grab the city name, I need to  slice [5]['short_name'], notice the 'types' is 'administrative_area_level_1'.

```
[{'long_name': 'Ｍ．Ｙ赤坂', 'short_name': 'Ｍ．Ｙ赤坂', 'types': ['premise']}, 
{'long_name': '11', 'short_name': '11', 'types': ['political', 'sublocality', 'sublocality_level_4']}, 
{'long_name': '2 Chome', 'short_name': '2 Chome', 'types': ['political', 'sublocality', 'sublocality_level_3']}, 
{'long_name': 'Akasaka', 'short_name': 'Akasaka', 'types': ['political', 'sublocality', 'sublocality_level_2']}, 
{'long_name': 'Minato-ku', 'short_name': 'Minato-ku', 'types': ['locality', 'political']}, 
{'long_name': 'Tōkyō-to', 'short_name': 'Tōkyō-to', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']}, 
{'long_name': 'Japan', 'short_name': 'JP', 'types': ['country', 'political']}, 
{'long_name': '107-0052', 'short_name': '107-0052', 'types': ['postal_code']}]
```

City names are in different position of the JSON format, and there is a problem with 'type', how do I differentiate 'administrative_area_level_1 and locality?
Is it possible to come up with a if statement to select exactly what I want? below is the whole code

```
import googlemaps
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

gmaps=googlemaps.Client(key='myapikey')
co=[(35.098129999999998, 135.71893),(26.211069999999999, 127.6876),(35.670479999999998, 139.74091999999999)]
for x, y in co:
   coor=(x,y)
   reverse_geocode_result = gmaps.reverse_geocode(coor)
   print (reverse_geocode_result[0]['address_components'])
```

Comment: Anybody who can help me? I am in desperate need of help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the city names but it needs several step. First, just take both locality and administrative_area_level_1 for each coordinates. Later on after you get all of them just eliminate the elements which are not city name.

```
import googlemaps
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

gmaps=googlemaps.Client(key='my key')
co=[(35.098129999999998, 135.71893),(26.211069999999999, 127.6876),(35.670479999999998, 139.74091999999999)]
s = [] # Same as your code but I make an empty list
for x, y in co:
   coor = (x,y)
   reverse_geocode_result = gmaps.reverse_geocode(coor)
   s.append(reverse_geocode_result[0]['address_components'])

result = [] # result for each element contains both local and adm_lvl_1
for j in s:
    l=[]
    for i in j:
        if i['types'][0]=='administrative_area_level_1':
            l.append(i['long_name'])
        elif i['types'][0]=='locality':
            l.append(i['long_name'])
    result.append(l)
```

Here the result will contains list of each elements with both locality and administrative_area_level_1. To distinguish the city you need to make a list of all city in japan. Then you can do looping for each result's element to get just the city name.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I have been waiting for a possible solution for too long! I am jumping right in to give it a try.